# How are the static variables in C++ code managed with JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My question is, Assume I have a c++ class with singleton and through JNI methods I call this singleton, does each time I call from java to c++ the singleton variable changed because its static, or it remains the same ? and does each time I call from java to c++ it run the method on new thread or no?

Example Code:

in Java:

```
class NativeLib
{
  public native void updateFrame();
}
```

in C/C++ :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_Company_NativeLib_NativeLib_updateFrame()
{
   sceneManager::getInstance()->updateFrame();
}
```

Does sceneManager::getInstance() at each call return new instance or the latest created instance since its a static variable.

my main problem in android my app crash without showing any kind of logCat information why it crashed.

but if I comment the sceneManager::getInstance()->updateFrame(); , it never crash so what I think is when ever Java make a call to C++ it is in a new thread which mean static variables does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the VM as a library of C/C++ code that your application has called into.  Sometimes it calls back into your code.

Singletons will not be recreated -- it's just a method call.  The Dalvik VM threads are just pthreads, and whichever thread executes the native call from Java-language code will be the thread that executes your C++ code.

Your best bet is to attach a native debugger.  FWIW, one way to crash with nothing in logcat is to have native recursion that overflows the stack.  Another way is to change the signal handlers for SIGSEGV / SIGBUS and friends.

Comment: Thanks Fadden for your answer, actually I did not changed the signal handlers at all, and I do not find any code of mine which using recursion.

What I think is GLSurfaceView.Renderer when I implements onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) method it works on different thread than the main thread.

and somehow I noticed that when I call c++ from java through jni the call happens in different thread, is this right ?

My question, when we load the .so file does VM keeps it in the memory until the app ends or for each call it loads again or sometimes it unload by the Dalvik VM, isn't each .so has its own stack?

Comment: The GLSurfaceView renderer runs on its own thread.  Native code called from that thread will run on that thread as well.  Only one instance of a .so file is loaded, and it's never unloaded by the VM.  There is no stack associated with a .so -- it's just code and data.  BTW, another reason apps can stop without warning is if somebody calls `exit()`, so make sure the library isn't doing that.

Comment: *"Singletons will not be recreated"* - does that always hold? If the shared object is unloaded, the the singleton will be destroyed on unload. Later, if another Java class reloads the library, then it will be recreated again.

Comment: The only way the shared library gets unloaded is if your code calls `dlclose()` -- the VM can't do this because it doesn't know the lifetime of your C++ objects.  Unloading the library does not destroy your objects; C++ destructors executing after dlclose() is a great way to cause a native crash.

Comment: May I ask question about threading and JaveEnv in android jni : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958854/android-jni-crash-in-global-and-local-ref-variables